# Associative array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I do not know what does it mean when it says: (it is from hook_block_view code for drupal)

> $block['content'] = array(
>             '#theme' => 'node_recent_block',
>             '#nodes' => $nodes,
>            );

I know $block['content'] is an associative array, also  I know that $node is  Full node object, Contains data that may not be safe.But about #theme, #nodes and 'node_recent_block.
 Can someone please tell me what do they mean.

I searched a lot but I did not find out what does it mean when there is a # before name of a key.
Thank you

Comment: An **element** of an associative array is assigned another **complete** associative array.

Comment: so what is the meaning of # sign?

Comment: The `#` has no special meaning - it is simply a part of the string, that is the array key

Comment: so you mean node_recent_block is  another associative array?

Comment: For all your future troubles with arrays: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($block['content'], true).'</pre>';` or `var_dump($block['content']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$block is an associative array, in which the element "content" is also an associative array.

Another way to define this would be:

```
$block = array(
    'content' => array(
         '#theme' => 'node_recent_block',
         '#nodes' => $nodes,
    ),
);
```

Inside an associative array **=>** is an assignment.

'content' is an array where '#theme' = 'node_recent_block' and '#nodes' = $nodes

***Edit:***

You could also assign the values like this:

```
$block['content']['#theme'] = 'node_recent_block';
$block['content']['#nodes'] = $nodes;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So I know we put $ before name of the variables in php. So what is node_recent_block?

Comment: 'node_recent_block' is just a string(text) value. It could be anything. You could set it to 'I like cookies', 'Hello World!', ...